# Method for passing class objects to the list in another class

Tags: java, oop

what will be the correct method to pass [from the main class Runner] the created Student objects to the List in the [public class Group] and to pass the Group objects to the List in the [public class Faculty]?
I tried to do it using the constructer, but it does not seem to be a good idea.

```
public class Runner {
public static void main(String[] args) {

 Student student1 = new Student ("Steve", "Faculty of Mathematics", "Group 21");
 Student student2 = new Student ("Oliver", "Faculty of Chemistry", "Group 22");

 Group group1 = new Group(21, (student1));
 Group group2 = new Group(22, (student2));

 Faculty faculty1 = new Faculty("Faculty of Mathematics", (group));

    }
}

public class Group { 
    private int groupNumber;
    private ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public Group(int groupNumber, Student student) {
        this.groupNumber = groupNumber;
        this.student = student;
    }

    //adds student objects to the list
    List<Student> getStudents() {
        studentList.add(student);
        return studentList;
    }
}

public class Faculty {
   private ArrayList<Group> groupList = new ArrayList<Group>();
//some code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One syntactically correct way of achieving this is to add `student` to `studentList` in the constructor, e.g.

```
public class Group {
  private int groupNumber;
  private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

  public Group(int groupNumber, Student student) {
    this.groupNumber = groupNumber;
    this.studentList.add(student);
  }

  // Getter should only return the list
  public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return studentList;
  }
}
```

However I would recommend you to change the constructor to accept a list of students and provide an `addStudent` method, e.g.

```
public class Group {
  private int groupNumber;
  private List<Student> studentList;

  public Group(int groupNumber, List<Student> students) {
    this.groupNumber = groupNumber;
    this.studentList =students;
  }

  public void addStudent(Student student) {
    studentList.add(student);
  }

  //adds student objects to the list
  public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return studentList;
  }
}
```

and change the caller to execute `Group group1 = new Group(21, new ArrayList<>(student1));`
**Remarks**

- You do not need to wrap arguments in `()`, e.g. `Group group1 = new Group(21, (student1));` can be written as `Group group1 = new Group(21, student1);`
- Getters should not have logic but only return the object

Answer (score 0):

A good `oop` technique would be to add an `append()` method in both `Group` class and `Faculty` class.

Since `Group` and `Faculty` both have lists that contain multiple objects, it would be a good idea to generate your students through a loop either getting inputs from the user or other way that you prefer to generate the students, and append them to the list in the `Group`'s `Arraylist`.

For the `Faculty` class this idea would work fine.

The heart of `oop` is not repeat the same code anywhere in your program. So my recommendation for your `Student` class is just to keep their private information in it. And when they are in a `Group` object it has their group information, same like that when the `Group` object is in a `Faculty` object it has the student's faculty information.

The basic structure for your `Group`, `Faculty` may be like below.

```
class Group {

  private int groupNumber;
  private ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

  public Group(int groupNumber) {
    this.groupNumber = groupNumber;

  }

  public void append(Student student){

    this.studentList.add(student);

  }

  public ArrayList getlist(){

    return this.studentList;

  }

}

class Faculty {
  private ArrayList<Group> groupList = new ArrayList<Group>();

  public Faculty(String faculty) {
  }

  public void append(Group group){

    this.groupList.add(group);

  }

  public ArrayList getlist(){

    return this.groupList;

  }

}
```

Then you can customise your Runner class class as you wish. Generating the students as you wish, through looping or as your wish.

```
class Runner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student student1 = new Student ("Steve");
    Student student2 = new Student ("Oliver");

    Group group1 = new Group(21);
    group1.append(student1);
    Group group2 = new Group(22);
    group2.append(student2);

    Faculty faculty1 = new Faculty("Faculty of Mathematics");
    faculty1.append(group1);
    faculty1.append(group2);

  }
}
```

A more efficient program would be like below. It generates the faculty according to your input and appends each group to it.

```
class Runner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int k=0;k<5;k++) {

      Faculty faculty1 = new Faculty(scanner.nextLine());
      for(int j=0;j<20;j++) {

        Group group = new Group(j);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          group.append(new Student(scanner.nextLine()));
        }
        faculty1.append(group);

      }

    }

  }
}
```